# Lua error "mutating non-standard global variable 'love'"

Tags: lua, global, var

I'm starting to code with love2d, so I installed love2d with the love2d support extension, there is no problem running the code and it works perfectly (I can draw hello world and have it appear on a black screen for example), but I keep getting the same warning every time I write "love".[image]

I have no idea why it happens

Comment: Is it really necessary to make `love` a global variable rather than local?

Comment: Why are you requiring `love` at all? `love` will be present in `main.lua`, you don't need to require it.